# Create model instance from non-JSON server response in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, backbone.js

I have a canonical model with an associated view:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return "/item/123"
  }
});
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

However, on the server-side, at url "/item/123", my Django application does not render JSON-formatted content, but an HTML template that is designed to be directly inserted inside the main page. How can I render the model without drastically changing how my server serves dynamic content? Is it even possible or am I misunderstanding the whole philosophy behind Backbone.js?

Just to give you a little background: I am in the process of refactoring the JS code of a Django web application by integrating Backbone.js. The app itself is not very large, but it makes heavy use of Ajax calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be loading templates in a `model`. The loading and rendering of templates would usually be the job of the `view`. Try loading the HTML directly with AJAX in the `render` method of your `view`:

```
 var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    var that = this;
    $.get('/item/123', function(html){
      that.$el.html(html);
    });
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: I realise this solution is not perfect with respect to Backbone.js, but it will be perfect to start the refactoring process.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent already, have a look at the django-app Tastypie, its the go-to solution for backend to backbone  and similar apps.

Without seing the code its hard to tell how much work it would be to move it all into Tastypie vs rolling your own solutions on a per-case basis, look over the documentation.